# Group Graphviz nodes as a table

Tags: graphviz

I've got the following Graphviz cluster with > 100 nodes rendered as a list, which looks pretty sloppy.

[image: Cluster]

I want to make this cluster to look like a table with n columns and k rows.
Here is an example of how diagram should look like:

[image: Diagram]

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve the desired result? Here's code I wrote trying to reproduce diagram above:

```rb
main = GraphViz.new(:G, rankdir: "TB")
rows = gets.to_i
columns = gets.to_i

1.upto(rows) do |row|
  row_graph = GraphViz.new("#{row}_row", rankdir: "LR")

  1.upto(columns) do |column|
    node_num = column + columns * (row - 1)
    row_graph.add_node("node_#{row}#{column}", label: "Node #{node_num}", shape: "box")
  end
end

main.output(png: "table_graph.png")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the dot files you have tried, what the result of these input files were and how the output should look like.

Comment: Graphviz has syntax to do exactly that: [HTML-like labels](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html#html), scroll down the page for examples.

Comment: @Progman sorry, I use ruby-graphviz library and have no experience with dot lang, I've added example of output I need

Comment: @МарсельМустафин Please [edit] your question to include the code attempts you used in ruby-graphviz and what the results of these code fragments were.

Comment: Please show some code of what you have tried sofar (possibly you need to play around with rank).

Comment: @Progman I've added code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
digraph {
  node [shape=box width=1]
  {rank=same Node1 Node2 Node3 Node4}
  {rank=same Node5 Node6 Node7 Node8}
  {rank=same Node9 Node10 Node11 Node12}
  Node1 -> Node5 -> Node9 [style=invis]
}
```

corresponding ruby code can be generated by `dot2ruby` tool